# Write a git alias for fast forward that works in any tracking branch?

Tags: git, alias

I'd like to create an alias to do the following:

Working in `master`, I would like `git ff` to perform `git merge --ff-only origin/master`.  But I want the same alias, when run in `maint` to perform `git merge --ff-only origin/maint`.  Likewise for any other tracking branches.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kudos to the other two answers, but there's an easier way, assuming that your branches are tracking the remote branches:

```
git pull --ff-only
```

Bonus: this will work even if your branches are tracking branches in a repo other than origin, or tracking differently-named branches. Also it's really short.

Comment: I assume this still performs the `fetch`? (not a huge deal if it does)

Comment: Would `git merge FETCH_HEAD` do the same thing, minus the fetch?

Comment: @keithjgrant: Yes, it still does the fetch. **If** you have just fetched the right branch (by itself), then `git merge --ff-only FETCH_HEAD` would do the same thing, yes. I wouldn't trust that for an alias though.

Comment: @keith: If you wanted this to work without a network, I'd take mipadi's answer and change `origin/$branch` to `$(git config --get branch.$branch.remote)/$(git config --get branch.$branch.merge)`.

Comment: D'oh! And kudos to _you_ for realizing that the OP's _actual_ problem could be solved in a simpler way than what he was asking for... +1.

Comment: @Jefromi a bit more complicated, one also has to cut off the `refs/heads/` part. As a result, I got this: `!sh -c 'branch=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD | sed s:refs/heads/::) && rbranch=$(git config --get branch.$branch.merge | sed s:refs/heads/::) && git merge --ff-only $(git config --get branch.$branch.remote)/$rbranch'`

Answer (score 5):

I think this could work:

```
[alias]
    ff = !sh -c 'branch=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD | cut -d '/' -f 3) && git merge --ff-only origin/$branch' -
```

Comment: I see no reason for using `!sh -c`

Answer (score 1):

There could be better ways of doing this, but this command should work:

```
git merge --ff-only origin/`git branch | grep "^\*" | cut -c 3-`
```

`git branch` lists all local branches; `grep "^\*"` selects the current one (which is prefixed by an asterisk), and `cut -c 3-` cuts away the asterisk, leaving only the branchname. The backticks paste the output of this command, namely the branchname, into the merge command.

Answer (score 0):

Building on @mipadi's answer and comments by @Cascabel:

```
[alias]
    ff = !branch=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD | cut -d '/' -f 3) && git merge --ff-only ${1:-$(git config --get branch.$branch.remote)/$( git config --get branch.$branch.merge | cut -d '/' -f 3)}
```

This means that `git ff` will fast-forward (without a fetch) to the current branch's remote tracking branch, as OP requested.

However, you can also use it with an optional argument of what branch (local or remote) to fast-forward to, for example `git ff master` would fast-forward the current branch to master (if possible).